# use of uninitialized value in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, valgrind

Hy,
I recently got a bug in my program when doing some refactoring. When analysing with valgrind

`valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes release/executable -c config.file 2> leakcheck`

I get the following output:

```
==16265== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==16265==    at 0x4F7F090: cv::CvtColorLoop_Invoker<cv::RGB2Gray<unsigned char> >::operator()(cv::Range const&) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.8)
==16265==    by 0x56B808F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.2.4.8)
==16265==    by 0x7293B39: ??? (in /usr/lib/libtbb.so.2)
==16265==    by 0x7291F8F: ??? (in /usr/lib/libtbb.so.2)
==16265==    by 0x56B8360: cv::parallel_for_(cv::Range const&, cv::ParallelLoopBody const&, double) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.2.4.8)
==16265==    by 0x4F88ADB: void cv::CvtColorLoop<cv::RGB2Gray<unsigned char> >(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, cv::RGB2Gray<unsigned char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.8)
==16265==    by 0x4F9601D: cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.8)
==16265==    by 0x42A75E: main (main.cpp:104)
==16265==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==16265==    at 0xA00D312: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.54.35.0)
```

Even when I reduce my code to the following minimal example, the issue remains:

```
VideoCapture cap = VideoCapture("../../testdata/synthetic/simple/output/Camera.avi");
Mat frame;
cap >> frame;
cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_RGB2GRAY);
imshow("test", frame);
waitKey(0);
```

Any idea what might cause this or how I can fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be an issue inside the OpenCV library, and not something you can directly do anything about. Unless, of course, you want to fix the issue in OpenCV, it *is* open-source.

Comment: 1. Test by using a second `Mat` (e.g. `Mat grayscaleFrame;`) as output of the color conversion 2. Saying "the issue remains", you mean that you have a visible bug or that you have the message from Valgrind? Also,  consider that OpenCV is currently at version 3.1, so this issue might have already been solved in the meantime.

Comment: I tried storing the result to a different Mat, but that didn't help. And I mean that valgrind still reports this. I have seen no bugs as a result of this, so it is not really causing any problem. I was just curious about the reason for this message. I will try updating my OpenCV version.